# Trying to compile MSVC-generated assembly from C++

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, masm32

C++ Source:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hi" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

cl command-line:

```
/MT /c cppTest.cpp /Fa"cppTest.asm" /Fo"cppTest.obj"
```

I want to modify the assembly it generates, so I try and compile cppTest.asm with ml

ml command-line:

```
/c /Cx /coff "cppTest.asm" /Fo"cppTest.obj"
```

Errors from ml:

```
cppTest.asm (1558) : fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : ?put@?basic_ostream@DU?$c
har_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@D@Z
```

cppTest.asm: http://pastebin.com/UVYpMqgH

I think it's because ml is having a hard time interpreting the generated asm code dealing with the C++ libraries

Comment: Well, according to [Hans](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41692288/2189500), the ability to compile the `/Fa` output was *broken a while ago*, so...  Looking at this particular output, we see that the `proc` for `put` is within `_TEXT   SEGMENT`, but the matching `endp` is outside the segment.  That seems like it might case a 'nesting' error.  I'm not convinced that trying to 'convert' large blocks of C++ to asm this way is a good plan.  What is your actual goal here?