# Can MSVC assembly listing generated with /FA be used to generate an executable?

Tags: visual-c++

Given a program compiled with /FA

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx

It will generate an asm file for each source file. How/can these files be used to re-generate the executable? Further to this would it still work if the asm files where modified, lets say I inserted some NOP's into a function?

Right now I have the asm files but no idea what to try next.

Comment: No, this got broken a while ago.  It is there purely for reference, not to actually assemble the generated file.  It is not practical anyway, having to do this for every single minor change in the source code gets exhausting *really* quickly.   This otherwise doesn't stop you from fixing the generated code and using MASM, it is not clear what help you need with that.  Do be specific.

Comment: I want to change the address used for some variables, obviously I would automate this instead of doing it by hand. Could you elaborate on " fixing the generated code and using MASM"? Using this could I replace all usages of a variable with other for instance?

Comment: Bah it won't let me edit my previous comment. Do you mean fixing the generated ASM files so that MASM can compile them?